# c3p0 connection pool queries

Tags: c3p0

I am using c3p0 connection pool and I have minPoolSize=1 maxPoolSize=5 and InitialPoolSize=5.

When server starts, i can see it is having 5 connection. But as the first request came, that no. increases to 10. And from then onwards it stays 10 as those 10 connections are handling that load. Now my question is, even if maxPoolSize is 5 , why it is creating another 5 conn. in the pool. Is it because of initialPoolSize ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you have two active pools. are you calling getConnection( user, password ) rather than the default getConnection()? c3p0 creates a distinct pool for each authentication. also, you can follow the number of active authentications via JMX.

initialPoolSize shouldn't have anything much to do with it. also, it's always a good idea, when trying to understand c3p0 issues, to make sure that the active config is what you expect it is. again, you can see most config parameters via JMX, or more simply, check your log files. c3p0 DataSources dump their configuration at INFO upon initialization.

Comment: I verified and it is only one pool in jmx and it is total 5 conn(maxPoolSize) when server starts but as soon as req came, it doubles(10) and stayed there forever(2 hrs test)

Comment: one pool or one DataSource? there can be multiple pools per DataSource, each DataSource is an mbean. what property are you looking at in JMX? what is the runtime value of maxPoolSize? please compare numConnectionsAllUsers and numConnectionsDefaultUser. are they the same?

Comment: You are right, there are multiple pool as it was configured for diff user. Sorry about the confusion, should have read the documenation