# Does c3p0 connection pooling ensures max pool size?

Tags: datasource, connection-pooling, c3p0

I've gone through several question, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942540/c3p0-connection-pool-queries) is somewhat related but doesn't answer my question.

Does the c3p0 connection pooling `maxPoolSize` ensures that the number of connections at a certain time never exceeds this limit? What if the `maxPoolSize=5` and 10 users start using the app exactly at the same time?

**My app. configurations**

```xml
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass"><value>${database.driverClassName}</value>/property>
    <property name="jdbcUrl"><value>${database.url}</value></property>
    <property name="user"><value>${database.username}</value></property>
    <property name="password"><value>${database.password}</value></property>
    <property name="initialPoolSize"><value>${database.initialPoolSize}</value>/property>
    <property name="minPoolSize"><value>${database.minPoolSize}</value></property>
    <property name="maxPoolSize"><value>${database.maxPoolSize}</value></property>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod"><value>200</value></property>
    <property name="acquireIncrement"><value>1</value></property>
    <property name="maxStatements"><value>0</value></property> 
    <property name="numHelperThreads"><value>3</value></property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>              
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

it is important to distinguish between DataSources and Connection pools.

maxPoolSize is enforced by c3p0 on a *per-pool* basis. but a single DataSource may own multiple Connection pools, as there is (and must be) a distinct pool for each set of authentication credentials. if only the default `dataSource.getConnection()` method is ever called, then maxPoolSize will be the maximum number of Connections that the pool acquires and manages. However, if Connections are acquired using `dataSource.getConnection( user, password )`, then the DataSource may hold up to `(maxPoolSize * num_distinct_users)` Connections.

to answer your specific question, if `maxPoolSize` is 5 and 10 clients hit a c3p0 DataSource simultaneously, no more than 5 of them will get Connections at first. the remaining clients will `wait()` until Connections are returned (or `c3p0.checkoutTimeout` has expired).

some caveats: c3p0 enforces `maxPoolSize` as described above. but there is no guarantee that, even if only a single per-auth pool is used, you won't occasionally see more than `maxPoolSize` Connections checked out. for example, c3p0 expires and destroys Connections asynchronously. as far as c3p0 is concerned, a Connection is gone once it has been made unavailable to clients and marked for destruction, not when it has actually been destroyed. so, it is possible that, if `maxPoolSize` is 5, that you'd occasionally observe 6 open Connections at the database. 5 connections would be active in the pool, while the 6th is in queue for destruction but not yet destroyed.

another circumstance where you might see unexpectedly many Connections open is if you modify Connection pool properties at runtime. in actual fact, the configuration of interior Connection pools is immutable. when you "change" a pool parameter at runtime, what actually happens is a new pool is started with the new configuration, and the old pool is put into a "wind-down" mode. Connections checked out of the old pool remain live and valid, but when they are checked in, they are destroyed. only when all old-pool Connections have been checked back in is the pool truly dead.

so, if you have a pool with `maxPoolSize` Connections checked out, and then alter a configuration parameter, you might transiently see a spike of up to `(2 * maxPoolSize)`, if the new pool is hit with lots of traffic before Connections checked out of the old pool have been returned. in practice, this is very rarely an issue, as dynamic reconfiguration is not so common, and Connection checkouts ought to be and usually are very brief, so the old-pool Connections disappear rapidly. but it can happen!

i hope this helps.

ps `acquireIncrement` is best set something larger than 1. `acquireIncrement` of 1 means no Connections are prefetched ahead of demand, so whenever load increases some Thread will directly experience the latency of Connection acquisition.

Comment: So if I use Guice to create the datasource (I assume this is not at run time), config the maxpoolsize to 100 (only use `getConnection()`), and i have in total 10 hosts for my service. Does this mean that the max number of connection to the DB would be 10*100? I saw far more than that number of idle connections (running `SELECT 1` or `SHOW TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL`) in `pg_stat_activity`, is this normal?

Comment: With 10 datasources using only the default authentication and `maxPoolSize` of 100, your application should generally use no more than 1000 connections at serverside. It may transiently exceed that, as Connections are `close()`ed asynchronously. But if it does dramatically or permanently exceed that, you have something to try to explain.

Comment: Perhaps the most common issue that leads to many times more Connections than expected not respecting the intended lifecycle of the pool. Is Guice or whatever initializing the DataSource once in your app's lifecycle (good), or is it constructing a new DataSource for every client (very, very bad). If the lifecycle is okay, you might want to check your settings: are you churning through Connections to quickly? Also, consider trying a larger `numHelperThreads` so asynchronous Connection close() in the Thread pool is less likely to fall behind.