# why hibernate constructs several c3p0 DataSource(s)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jmx, c3p0

I use hibernate with c3p0 in my web app.

In jconsole I see com.mchange.v2.c3p0 with C3PORegistry and PooledDataSource(s)

[image]

I do not understand why my app contains several DataSources.
Only one of them constructed according to my initial parameters (numConnections = 10).

Others have numConnections = 0

I have nothing special in my c3p0 configuration:

```
c3p0.acquire_increment
c3p0.min_size
c3p0.max_size
```

Does hibernate really need all this DataSources?

Can I set number to one DataSource?

And is it good idea to have only one DataSource?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are values you set for MINPOOLSIZE and MAXPOOLSIZE?

Comment: MINPOOLSIZE = 1 and MAXPOOLSIZE = 250

Comment: I think you may get answer from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932846/does-c3p0-connection-pooling-ensures-max-pool-size