# Tomcat using c3p0 Datasource, maxPoolSize exceeded

Tags: java, tomcat, datasource, connection-pooling, c3p0

I have configured Tomcat to use a ComboPooledDataSource, by adding the following in my context.xml.

```
<Resource
    name="jdbc/abcdatasource"
    auth="Container"
    type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
    maxPoolSize="20"
    minPoolSize="5"
    maxIdleTime="3000"
    acquireIncrement="1"
    user="abc"
    password="pw_here"
    driverClass="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    jdbcUrl="jdbc:oracle:thin:@abc.def.ghi.net:1521:BLAH"
/>
```

I want to limit the db connections to 20, as defined in the maxPoolSize, but my open connections are exceeding this number.  Yesterday, for example, I had 35 open connections.  My logs are capturing the following.

```
2014-09-11 00:37:47,077  INFO [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2] NewPooledConnection:725 -  - [c3p0] Exceptions occurred while trying to close a PooledConnection's resources normally.
2014-09-11 00:37:47,077  INFO [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2] NewPooledConnection:735 -  - [c3p0] NewPooledConnection close Exception.
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection timed out
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logoff(T4CConnection.java:481)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.close(PhysicalConnection.java:1203)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:549)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:234)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.destroyResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:470)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:964)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
2014-09-11 00:37:47,078  WARN [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2] BasicResourcePool:972 -  - Failed to destroy resource: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@3ca5d95d
java.sql.SQLException: Some resources failed to close properly while closing com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@3ca5d95d
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:571)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:234)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.destroyResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:470)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:964)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
```

Given this information, what is a likely cause for my open connections to be in excess of my maxPoolSize?

I know there are related stackoverflow threads, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932846/does-c3p0-connection-pooling-ensures-max-pool-size) and [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942540/c3p0-connection-pool-queries) but it's not clear to what the issue could be in my case.  In these similar threads, there were multiple connection pools - but I would expect one distinct connection pool when I configure my web application container to use the c3p0 ComboPooledDataSource. Maybe I'm missing something there...

Any help would be very greatly appreciated!!!!!

Edit 1:  For some additional context, this is not a new application.  It has been up and running for years.  What is new, however, is using Tomcat with the c3p0 datasource.  This issue occurred after transitioning from WebLogic to Tomcat.

Edit 2: I failed to provide what may be very useful logging information when I originally created this post.  DEADLOCK issue captured in log4j is shown below. I have been closely monitoring the connections since I noticed this issue and the connection increase seems to be associated with the deadlock issue.  If I had to guess, I would say that it's creating a new connection pool after the deadlock.

```
2014-09-11 11:36:45,320  WARN [Timer-0] ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner:608 -  - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@1c203f2b -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
2014-09-11 11:36:45,323  WARN [Timer-0] ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner:624 -  - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@1c203f2b -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status:
        Managed Threads: 3
        Active Threads: 3
        Active Tasks:
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask@4a50503d (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask@5ec3fae8 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask@148dc5f3 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1)
        Pending Tasks:
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask@67bedf0f
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask@242686ff
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@5d68e1e3
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@10c62dfe
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@42f5874c
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@585b0ec
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@c2258c9
Pool thread stack traces:
        Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2,5,main]
                java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
                java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
                oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Unknown Source)
                oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(Unknown Source)
                oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(Unknown Source)
                oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
                oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
                oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
                oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1104)
                oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1075)
                oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.receive(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:106)
                oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logoff(T4CConnection.java:465)
                oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.close(PhysicalConnection.java:1203)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:549)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:234)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.destroyResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:470)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:964)
                com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
        Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0,5,main]
                java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
                java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
                oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Unknown Source)
                oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(Unknown Source)
                oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(Unknown Source)
                oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
                oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
                oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
                oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1104)
                oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1075)
                oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.receive(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:106)
                oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logoff(T4CConnection.java:465)
                oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.close(PhysicalConnection.java:1203)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:549)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:234)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.destroyResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:470)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:964)
                com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
        Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1,5,main]
                java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
                java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
                oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Unknown Source)
                oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(Unknown Source)
                oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(Unknown Source)
                oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
                oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
                oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
                oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1104)
                oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1075)
                oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.receive(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:106)
                oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logoff(T4CConnection.java:465)
                oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.close(PhysicalConnection.java:1203)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:549)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:234)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.destroyResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:470)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:964)
                com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
```

The c3p0 version that is being used is 0.9.1.2

Comment: Couple of questions: How are you measuring the open connections (at the database or just printing the connection objects in the Java code)? And how are you acquiring connections from the code? getConnection() or getConnection(username,password)? 

From your exception trace, looks like connections are not getting closed. Can you find out the reason for that from a DB point of view?

Comment: Primarily, from the server I'm running tomcat on I measure open connections using the command # netstat -an | grep 1521.  Our DBA also checked the open connections solely from a database point of view and it was consistent with what i was seeing.

Comment: Regarding the method of acquiring a connection, that is something I can dig into, but I was under the impression that even if the getConnection(username,password) method was used, it wouldn't create more than one connection pool since I have exactly one username and password configured in the context.xml.

Comment: It would if we use a different username. But I'm thinking the error during `close()` call. Can you debug your way to catch the root cause for the timeout?

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I updated Tomcat's server.xml and set autoDeploy=false and I have not had any issues since.

My c3p0 connection pool settings are in Tomcat's context.xml and any modification to this file at runtime would result in the application being redeployed and an additional connection pool created. Setting autoDeploy to false prevents this Tomcat behavior which had the unwanted c3p0 connection pool side effect.